# What does it mean that something is an incompatible package?

Tags: package, help

I have some [issues](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/13670) going on with my emacs and am getting an error where the stacktrace seems to indicate a potential issue with the parinfer package. I run `describe-package` on it and get

```
parinfer is an incompatible package.

     Status: Incompatible in ‘parinfer-20180904.844/’ (unsigned).
    Version: 20180904.844
    Summary: Simpler Lisp editing
   Requires: dash-2.13.0 (not available), cl-lib-0.5
   Homepage: https://github.com/DogLooksGood/parinfer-mode
   Keywords: parinfer 
Other versions: 20180904.844 (melpa).
```

Can someone help me understand what this means? What does it mean that it is incompatible? I can see its functions in `M-x` though it doesn't seem to be working. Is it because of `dash-2.13.0 (not available)`? How can something be not available? What would the solution be?

Comment: I agree that "incompatible package" with no explanation doesn't tell you much. I'd guess that it's that unavailable version of `dash` that's the problem, but maybe there are two problems. You might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug` to ask for the doc to define "incompatible package" here.

Comment: @Drew even more confusingly I do have dash installed
```   Status: Installed in ‘dash-20200524.1947/’ (unsigned).
    Version: 20200524.1947```
which should be a higher version than 2.13.0 right?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the version numberings are different - different system: version number 2.13.0 versus a date + sequence number. I suspect that the numbering with the date comes from MELPA. But I'm no expert on package.el etc.